# Adding class to a sibling once sibling is found

Tags: jquery

If I am using the following statement...

```
if ($('divA').siblings().text() == "1") {
 the code here needs to add a class to that specific sibling where text = 1
}
```

How would I select that sibling div to add class?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('divA').siblings().filter(function(index) {
    return $(this).text() == "1";
 }).addClass('yourClass');
```

You can use the [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function to reduce the `.siblings()` collection to those that only return true for your condition, then use `.addClass()` to add your class to the filtered siblings.